# Kineticjs - How can I return a Kinetic.Image()?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs, layer

I need to allow a user to make some patterns and render them as images on a canvas. For that, I've followed the steps described by the very good answer in [KineticJS Fill with pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163143/kineticjs-fill-with-pattern).

I run into trouble when I want to seperate the different steps into their own function save these patterns for use in another function. My strategy was to write a `.toDataURL()` method and return that, which has been proving difficult.

```
     function make_pattern(type, color) {
var pattern = document.createElement('canvas');
var cont=document.createElement('div');
var sta= new Kinetic.Stage({
    container:cont,
    width: 500,
height: 500
});
var lay=new Kinetic.Layer({
    width: 500,
height: 500
});

pattern.width = 40;
pattern.height = 40;
var pattco = pattern.getContext('2d');

switch (type) {
    case 'line' :
        pattco.moveTo(0, 40);
        pattco.lineTo(40, 0);
        pattco.lineWidth = 8;
        pattco.strokeStyle = color;
        pattco.stroke();
        break;
    case 'arc':
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            pattco.beginPath();
            pattco.arc(40, 0, 20, (0.6 + i) * Math.PI, (0.9 + i) * Math.PI, false);
            pattco.lineWidth = 4;
            pattco.strokeStyle = color;
            pattco.stroke();
        }
        break;
    case 'circ':
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            pattco.beginPath();
            pattco.arc(Math.floor(Math.random() * 16), Math.floor(Math.random() * 16), Math.floor(Math.random() * 2), 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
            pattco.lineWidth = 2;
            pattco.fillStyle = color;
            pattco.stroke();
        }
        break;
    case 'rect':
        pattco.fillStyle = color;
        pattco.fillRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
        pattco.fillRect(20, 20, 20, 20);
        break;
}

var img = new Image();
img.onload =function() {
    var patt = new Kinetic.Image({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        fillPatternImage: img,
        width: 500,
        height: 500 
    });
    lay.add(patt);
    sta.add(lay);
    sta.draw();


       };
      img.src=pattern.toDataURL();

     return sta.toDataURL();
```

I can't seem to draw the `Kinetic.Image()` onto my container here, which is precisely what I am missing! I'd be very grateful for any help. Thanks.

Comment: where is you .toDataURL()  function?

Comment: It's right at the bottom of the function. My main difficulty and the point of this question is to ask how I might return this value, given that it can be changed by the user.

Comment: I found after some searching that a way to do this was to create a `Kinetic.Group` in the function, add the image to it on the load event and return the group. This still feels like a roundabout way and I would really prefer to have the `Kinetic.Image` object accessible directly. However the load event required, before which the image doesn't exist, makes this difficult for me to grasp.